# Pushing new instance of self onto nav controller weirdness

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

OK, bear with me. I have a storyboard based IOS app that:

1. Framed as a TabBar main navigation. One tab segues to a NavigationController. Fine.
2. In the navigation controller main view I have a CollectionController, also good.
3. When selecting a Collection item, I "push" (from a different storyboard) a UIViewController that works like a charm.
4. From the UIViewController, depending on user action, I segue to a second UIViewController
5. From the second UIViewController, depending on user action, I attempt to push a new instance of the second UIViewController (basically push myself even though I instantiate a new blank one from the storyboard).

When I do this, I am brought to the view controller noted in #3 above.

I'm thinking it has to do with the segue from #4 versus #4 pushing using navigation controller. Anyone?

TIA
Frank

Comment: How are you pushing this new instance of self? How did you set this up in the storyboard? Did you make a new scene that has the same class as self?

Comment: When I get an event I am locating the storyboard and :`code`[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailEditController"];`code`

Comment: But is that identifier the same one you had for the first time this controller was pushed, or is this a separate scene with a different identifier?

Comment: Same identifier. Basically I want to re-use the behavior of current scene/controller as it is all data driven.

Comment: I found the problem. I had logic in the viewWillDisappear that had assumptions it would be the only one and would execute and unwind segue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you shouldn't do it that way. You could either use an unwind segue to go back to that controller or do popToViewController:animated: in code to go back to that controller. This will go back to the same instance of that controller which may not be what you want.

If you really need a new instance, you should create a new scene in the storyboard. You can create this new scene by copy and paste on the one you already have -- that way, it will have the same view. After you copy and paste it, you can move it to where you want, give it a new identifier, and hook up its new segue..